# What is the difference between .data('sth') and .attr('data-sth')?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

*When should I use one or the other?*

The only difference I noticed is that with a click event

`var $sth = $('.selector').data('sth');`
seems to be cached, while

`var $sth = $('.selector').attr('data-sth');`
gets newly assigned every click.

What is the use-case for `.data('sth');` ?